# Subscript requires array or pointer type. And error C2664. I am new to c++, but still I don't understand. I added reference and pointer to reference

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int& niz(int& arr, int vel){
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    int vel;
    cout << "Unesi velicinu: ";
    cin >> vel;
    int* arr = new int[vel];
    niz(arr, vel);

}
```

I tried to remove pointers or ampersand on function but it doesn't work. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: You can't learn C++ by trial and error. It's a much more complicated language than you imagine. It takes *years* to master.

Comment: C++ must be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by trial and error.

Comment: `arr` is an `int` so you can't subscript it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int& niz(int& arr, int vel){
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

should be

```
int* niz(int* arr, int vel){
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

or

```
int* niz(int arr[], int vel){
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vel;i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Try and error is a very important part of learning almost any programming language and many other things. But starting with a good book is equally, if not more, important if you want to make decent progress and not get stuck in a lot of language details which can possibly overwhelm a new learner, or, form some bad programming habits from bad books/guidance. I don't have one to recommend, but I am sure you can find out by a quick google.

For this particular problem you are facing, I suggest that you do some more search on **pointer, array and reference**. It's very essential c++ knowledge that no perfect library that gurus may recommend to you can replace. Happy learning c++.

Comment: `int arr[], int vel` is a really bad interface, which is typically promoted by garbage coding websites. We should not promote it further at SO - modern C++ offers much better alternatives.

Comment: @Evg what if one need to interface with c library? Get rid of bad c from c++ completely? Knowing one thing is different from using it carelessly or encouraging the using of it. The lack of understanding of `reference, pointer, and array` demonstrated by this problem need to be addressed for Luka, or it will come back haunting him repeatedly.

Comment: The question doesn't mention any need for an interface to a C library. I have no objection for references and pointers, but their usage should be _explained_. I don't see how it is addressed in this answer. It simply gives a solution without any analysis and discussion of better alternatives.

Comment: He (Luka) doesn't understand the difference between pointer, reference, and array. This is evident from the problem he is facing. This cannot be circumvented by skipping basics and learn modern c++. A new learner should be encouraged to use modern c++, but not discouraged from understand the basics. Make sense?

Comment: But how does this answer teaches basics without explaining the suggested code changes? Does it explain what a reference/pointer is? Does it explain why you can apply a subscript operator to a pointer but not to a reference? Does it explain the difference between using `int*` and `int[]`? What _does_ it explain?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But it points out what the error messages he received is about. And by comparing what changes are made between code of his and mine, a rationale learner will find out or find a direct to search for why it has to be the other way. The basics likely needs a whole chapter to teach, you seriously think I should make the effort here?

Comment: I seriously think that good SO answers should explain things not just highlight code changes to formally fix a problem. Even a short explanation with references to good sources would make a difference.

Comment: Honestly I don't have one handy. Please feel free to do what you're promoting. Thanks!

Comment: I'm already doing it in my own answers, but I can't answer all questions here. IMO, Jason Liam in the comments section already did everything that is needed for this question. A rationale learner would follow that reference, read some good introductory book and be happy with learning C++ basics.

Comment: So the only thing I can do to make you happy is delete this answer?

Comment: No. You can improve it.